# android ndk-gdb fails to load symbols

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb

Using android-ndk-r7b/samples/hello-jni as a debugging starting point, I built the jni with

ndk-build V=1 NDK_DEBUG=1

```
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/x86/lib*.so
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
mkdir -p ./libs/armeabi
install -p /cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
mkdir -p ./libs/armeabi
/cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/prebuilt/windows/bin/echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi" > ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
/cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/prebuilt/windows/bin/echo "directory C:/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include jni C:/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Cygwin         : Generating dependency file converter script
mkdir -p obj/
mount | awk -f /cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/build/awk/gen-cygwin-deps-converter.awk > obj/convert-dependencies.sh && chmod +x obj/convert-dependencies.sh
Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
/cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org -fpic  -ffunction-sections  -funwind-tables  -fstack-protector  -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__  -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__   -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te  -mtune=xscale  -msoft-float  -mthumb  -Os  -fomit-frame-pointer  -fno-strict-aliasing  -finline-limit=64  -Ijni  -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -O0 -g  -IC:/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include  -c   jni/hello-jni.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o  && ./obj/convert-dependencies.sh ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d
SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
/cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -Wl,-soname,libhello-jni.so  -shared  --sysroot=C:/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm  ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o    C:/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a    -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack   -lc -lm  -o obj/local/armeabi/libhello-jni.so
Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so
mkdir -p ./libs/armeabi
install -p ./obj/local/armeabi/libhello-jni.so ./libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so
/cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded ./libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so
```

I now start the debugging process.
1. I start up a emulator
2. I debug the application within eclipse.
3. I make sure that I'm in the hello-jni directory
4. I enter ndk-gdb --verbose

I've looked at other posts on the subject and the ndk-gdb output always seems to end with something that looks like the following

```
warning: shared library handler failed to enable breakpoint
0xafd0c51c in epoll_wait () from /home/zayac/code/android-ndk-r5/samples/hello-jni2/obj/local/armeabi/libc.so
```

It seems that its ready to go with the "epoll_wait ()..." text.

When I run ndk-gdb --verbose I never see that text.  I just get the waring and the (gdb) prompt.  Here's the output...

```
  
Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b
Using default adb command: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29
Using ADB flags:
Using auto-detected project path: .
Found package name: com.example.hellojni
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi
Device API Level: 10
Device CPU ABI: armeabi
Compatible device ABI: armeabi
Found debuggable flag: true
Found device gdbserver: /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/gdbserver
Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Using toolchain prefix: /cygdrive/c/Users/pcarreir/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi
Found data directory: '/data/data/com.example.hellojni'
Found running PID: 7806
Launched gdbserver succesfully.
Setup network redirection
## COMMAND: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb shell run-as com.example.hellojni lib/gdbserver +debug-socket --attach 7806
## COMMAND: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb forward tcp:5039 localfilesystem:/data/data/com.example.hellojni/debug-socket
Attached; pid = 7806
## COMMAND: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb pull /system/bin/app_process obj/local/armeabi/app_process
Listening on sockaddr socket debug-socket
19 KB/s (5660 bytes in 0.284s)
Pulled app_process from device/emulator.
## COMMAND: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb pull /system/lib/libc.so obj/local/armeabi/libc.so
56 KB/s (273868 bytes in 4.730s)
Pulled libc.so from device/emulator.
GNU gdb 6.6
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i586-mingw32msvc --target=arm-elf-linux".
(no debugging symbols found)
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/system/bin/linker: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libc.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstdc++.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libm.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
liblog.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libcutils.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libz.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libutils.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libbinder.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libexpat.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libcrypto.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libicuuc.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libicui18n.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libsqlite.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libssl.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libnativehelper.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libnetutils.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libEGL.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libwpa_client.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libhardware_legacy.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libpixelflinger.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libhardware.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libui.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libgui.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libsurfaceflinger_client.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libcamera_client.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libemoji.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libjpeg.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libskia.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libGLESv1_CM.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libskiagl.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libdvm.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libGLESv2.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libETC1.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libsonivox.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libmedia.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libnfc_ndef.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libandroid_runtime.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libvorbisidec.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_amrnb_common.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_enc_common.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_avc_common.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_foundation.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_color_conversion.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libmedia_jni.so: No such file or directory.
Error while 0xafd0c738 in ?? ()
gdb: Unable to get location for thread creation breakpoint: requested event is not supported
mapping shared library sections:
libexif.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libsoundpool.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstlport.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libwebcore.so: No such file or directory.
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
warning: shared library handler failed to enable breakpoint
(gdb)
```

When I enter a gdb command like **list**, I get

> (gdb) No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem because libs/armeabi/gdb.setup contained CR (CRLF) characters.
After removing them on the development host (project directory) it worked without re-installing.

gdb.setup seems to be written by ndk-build which seems to introduce the CR chars on Windows (not on Linux).